# taking objects from a list box to another form by pressing a button

Tags: c#, arrays, random, listbox

I have a `ListBox` that I add words to, on the next page I want to be able to press a guess `Button` and it shall bring one of the words up. What is the code to do this?

```
private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void randomNumber()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    //randomWord = wordBank[rand.Next(0, (wordbank))];
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //string s = arraylist[rand.Next(arraylist.Count)];
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example?

Comment: What did you try? Why do you talk about 'obejcts'  and 'words' - now which do you mean? Do you just want to quote one string or actually remove it? Taking an object mean to remove it from its original place.. Also: Edit the qurstion: Never put code in a comment!